# fluent nhibernate hasmany merge

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm a still discovring nhibernate, so maybe my question is a little bit stupid :(

I have the following model:
Questionnaire -n-> Answer -1-> Question

```
public class Questionnaire : IEquatable<Questionnaire>
{       
    public virtual int? Id {get;set;}

    public virtual IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionnaireMap : ClassMap<Questionnaire>
{
    public QuestionnaireMap()
    {
        this.Table("Questionnaire");
        this.Id(questionnaire => questionnaire.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        this.HasMany(questionnaire => questionnaire.Answers).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse().KeyColumn("QuestionnaireId");
    }
}

public class Answer : IEquatable<Answer>
{
    public virtual int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual int? QuestionnaireId { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Value { get; set; }      

    public virtual Questionnaire Questionnaire { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerMap : ClassMap<Answer>
{
    public AnswerMap()
    {
        this.Table("Questionnaire_Answer");

        this.CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(answer => answer.QuestionId).Mapped()
            .KeyReference(answer => answer.Questionnaire, "QuestionnaireId").Mapped();

        this.Map(answer => answer.Value);
    }
}
```

I'm able to get my entities and to save a new entity.

Unfortunately, there is some cases where 'updating' it does not work.

If I remove all the answers of a questionnaire and then call session.Merge(answer) then everything works fine.

However, if I add a new answer to a questionnaire

```
questionnaire.Answers.Add(new Answer { BoolValue = true, QuestionId = 3, Questionnaire = questionnaire });
```

then I get an exception (System.Reflection.TargetException: "Non-static method requires a target").

By using a sql profiler I see that nhibernate tries to insert a new answer with a null as questionnaireId (with is of course a non-nullable column).
I think that my mapping is wrong, but I cannot see what is the problem.

Can someone help me?

thanks & regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was not able to solve it, I removed the composite primary key of Answer and add an identity column.
Thus my mapping becomes:

```
public AnswerMap()
    {
        this.Table("Questionnaire_Answer");
        this.Id(answer => answer.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        this.References(answer => answer.Questionnaire, "QuestionnaireId").Not.Nullable();
        this.Map(answer => answer.QuestionId).Not.Nullable();
        this.Map(answer => answer.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping for `Questionnaire` is wrong. Your key is nullable, but you'v mapped it as not nullable (it's by default). I suggest you to change your `Questionnaire.Id` to **not-nullable** integer.

```
public class Questionnaire : IEquatable<Questionnaire>
{   
    // NOT NULLABLE    
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**:

```
public class Answer : IEquatable<Answer>
{
    public virtual int QuestionId { get; set; }

    // NOT NULLABLE - it's used by composite key
    public virtual int QuestionnaireId { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Value { get; set; }      
    public virtual Questionnaire Questionnaire { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I did this modification but it was also not working. Thus, I added an identity column to the answer table and removed the composite key. Then, everything went fine. Thanks anyway for your help (these mappings were obviously wrong) :)